# Sum multiple dynamic columns in where Clause

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a product table , with 5 statuses, Status1,Status2,Status3,Status4. each of this column represents stock qty under each status.

The customers have allocated statues , some customers might have allowed status 1 and 2, some might have status2,3,4 etc.
when customer logged in I want to show customer sum of allocated stock status , say if customer is allowed status 1 and 3, then I wanna show customer sum on status 1 and status3.

If sum is less than 1 then i dont wanna show that product.I wanna do this condition in query so I will have 50 (fixed) product per call.

if I do this condition in view then I wont have fixed 50 products per call.

So my question is how to add column dynamically in Where clause and use condition < 1.

```
public int GetProductsByCategory(string productCode,string[] StockStatus)
             {
              IEnumerable<SGProduct> query = MongoContext.Products.AsQueryable<SGProduct>().AsEnumerable()
            .Where(.........);

             }
```

The stockStatus array contains customer allowed statuese, like Statu1,Statu2.
Thanks

**EDIT**
to make it simple and explain it better , let say I have a method that takes two parameter first one product code and second status (string array).

```
   public int GetProductsByCategory(string productCode,string[] StockStatus)
{
IEnumerable<SGProduct> query = MongoContext.Products.AsQueryable<SGProduct>().AsEnumerable()
            .Where(.........);
}
```

how can I make Where clause dynamic, so I can pass this method something like:

```
GetProductsByCategory("ProdA",new string[] { "Status1", "Status2" };)
```

**Or**

```
 GetProductsByCategory("ProdA",new string[] { "Status4", "Status7" };)
```

Comment: Please use paragraphs to break up your text. Please specify sample inputs and outputs. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show your classes and an example of the result you want.

Comment: What is `MongoContext.Products.AsQueryable<SGProduct>().AsEnumerable()` supposed to be good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question!

Let's start with the `Product` entity:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int Status1 { get; set; }
    public int Status2 { get; set; }
    public int Status3 { get; set; }
    public int Status4 { get; set; }
    public int Status5 { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of a `string[]` to express a set of statuses, I'd suggest to use an `enum` with the `[Flags]`attribute.

```
[Flags]
public enum StatusFlags
{
    None = 0,
    Status1 = 1 << 0, // 1
    Status2 = 1 << 1, // 2
    Status3 = 1 << 2, // 4
    Status4 = 1 << 3, // 8
    Status5 = 1 << 4 // 16
}
```

The master plan is to develop a `Select` overload `public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TResult>(this IQueryable<Product> products, StatusFlags flags, Expression<Func<Product, int, TResult>> resultSelector)` that lets you project products into something based on the product and the sum of some statuses.

**Examples**: (given a `IQueryable<Product> products` and a `StatusFlags flags`, e.g. `StatusFlags.Status3 | StatusFlags.Status5`)

Sum all statuses in `flags` over products with `ProductCode` "ProdA" (+/- what you asked for):

```
products
.Where(p => p.ProductCode == "ProdA")
.Select(flags, (p, s) => s) // resolves to .Select(p => p.Status3 + p.Status5)
.Sum()
```

Select `Id`, `ProductCode` and the sum of the selected statuses per product:

```
products
.Select(flags, (p, s) => new { p.Id, p.ProductCode, Status = s}) // resolves to .Select(p => new { p.Id, p.ProductCode, Status = p.Status3 + p.Status5 })
```

Group products by `ProductCode` and get the sum of the selected statuses per group:

```
products
.Select(flags, (p, s) => new { p.ProductCode, Status = s }) // resolves to .Select(p => new { p.ProductCode, Status = p.Status3 + p.Status5 })
.GroupBy(cs => cs.ProductCode, (code, css) => new { ProductCode = code, Status = css.Sum(cs => cs.Status) });
```

**Implementation**

First we need some infrastructure that I copy out of one of my projects: An `ExpressionVisitor` that replaces parameters in an expression by a replacement expression.

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="ExpressionVisitor"/> to replace parameters with actual expressions.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> _replacements;

    /// <summary>
    /// Init with parameters and their replacements.
    /// </summary>
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<ParameterExpression, Expression>> replacements)
    {
        _replacements = replacements.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        Expression replacement;
        return _replacements.TryGetValue(node, out replacement) ? replacement : node;
    }
}
```

...et voilà

```
public static class ProductExtensions
{
    private static readonly ConstantExpression _zero = Expression.Constant(0); // constant 0 for no StatusFlags

    // StatusFlag : Product => Status property of Product
    private static readonly Dictionary<StatusFlags, Expression<Func<Product, int>>> _propertySelectorsByStatus = new Dictionary<StatusFlags, Expression<Func<Product, int>>>
    {
        { StatusFlags.Status1, p => p.Status1 },
        { StatusFlags.Status2, p => p.Status2 },
        { StatusFlags.Status3, p => p.Status3 },
        { StatusFlags.Status4, p => p.Status4 },
        { StatusFlags.Status5, p => p.Status5 }
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Project a products into a result built from the product and the sum of the Product.StatusX selected by <paramref name="flags"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="products">The source products.</param>
    /// <param name="flags">Flags selecting the specific statuses to add up.</param>
    /// <param name="resultSelector">Expression to select the result from a product and the added statuses.</param>
    public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TResult>(this IQueryable<Product> products, StatusFlags flags, Expression<Func<Product, int, TResult>> resultSelector)
    {
        if (products == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(products));
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

        var pProduct = resultSelector.Parameters[0];
        var pStatus = resultSelector.Parameters[1];
        var xStatusSum = _propertySelectorsByStatus
            .Where(kv => (kv.Key & flags) != 0) // flags has the specified status
            .Select(kv => new ParameterReplaceVisitor(new[] { new KeyValuePair<ParameterExpression, Expression>(kv.Value.Parameters[0], pProduct) }).Visit(kv.Value.Body)) // pProduct.StatusX
            .Aggregate((Expression)null, (sum, status) => sum == null ? status : Expression.Add(sum, status)) // pProduct.StatusX + pProduct.StatusY + ...
            ?? _zero; // fallback for StatusFlags.None
        var body = new ParameterReplaceVisitor(new[] { new KeyValuePair<ParameterExpression, Expression>(pStatus, xStatusSum) }).Visit(resultSelector.Body);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, TResult>>(body, pProduct); // p => TResult
        return products.Select(selector);
    }
}
```